# how to you sort a array using a config

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

how do you sort an array file using a config value on Ramda
I have tried using R.map then add a condition R.includes and if it's true return value R.always
but i keep on getting  [ [Function], [Function], [Function] ]

the code I use

```
args = [ 'BBQ', 'Tuna', 'Cake', 'Wood' ]

config = [ { foodType: 'Tuna' },
           { foodType: 'BBQ' },
           { foodType: 'Cake' } ]

const getPriority = R.curry((config, args) =>
  R.pipe(
    R.map(
      R.pipe(
        R.prop('foodType'),
          R.ifElse(
           R.includes(args),
           R.always
        )
      )
    ),
    R.flatten,
  )(config)
);

Expected result is [ 'Tuna', 'BBQ', 'Cake' ]
```

any idea why I keep on getting [ [Function], [Function], [Function] ]

Comment: First off, you're using `ifElse` incorrectly.  It takes three arguments: functions for the condition, the consequence, and the alternative -- all taking the same input values.  However, it's not at all clear to me what you're trying to do.  Does `pluck('foodType', config)` not give you what you want?

Comment: i just need to sort the Args using the config first value will be Tuna if it got Tuna and so on and i think pluck will not work with that but will try

Comment: But  you're not simply sorting the args.  You're filtering them as well, right?  Else where is `'Wood'` in your suggested output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to make a guess at your requirements here from what I see of the code.  It seems to me that you want the foodTypes from `config` which are also to be found in `args`, sorted by the order they appear in `config`.  Is that right?

If so, this code would seem to work:

```js
const getPriority = (args) => (config) =>
  config .reduce ((a, {foodType}) => args.includes(foodType) ? [...a, foodType] : a, [])

const args = [ 'BBQ', 'Tuna', 'Cake', 'Wood' ]

const config = [ { foodType: 'Tuna' },
                 { foodType: 'Sprouts' }, // added -- not everything is in output
                 { foodType: 'BBQ' },
                 { foodType: 'Cake' } ]

console .log (getPriority (args) (config))
```

We could use some Ramda function for that if we chose:

```js
const getPriority = (args) =>
  reduce ((a, {foodType}) => includes (foodType, args) ? append(foodType, a) : a, [])
```

Or perhaps a different version:

```js
const getPriority = (args) =>
  pipe(pluck('foodType'), filter(flip(includes)(args)))
```

... but they don't seem to add much to this function.  I'm one of the founders of Ramda, but I think of it as a tool to use when it helps, not a new framework or mini-language to code with.  Here it doesn't seem to offer much of use.